# How to resize image with keeping the original image resoultion and quality using imageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, image-conversion, ubuntu-14.10

I have an icon image that i need to resize it to be little bit smaller, however, am using the `imageMagick` on `ubuntu`, i have tried many options just like:

```
convert inupt.gif -resize 30x29 -density 72 -quality 75 output.gif
```

The problem that each time i create a resized image, it lost some of the original image resolution/quality.

So my question is to resize the image without losing the original image quality and resolution.

Original Image : [image]

Output Image : [image]

Comment: How big is the original image? Why are you surprised that the quality reduces when you specify that you only want 75% quality?

Comment: @MarkSetchell this is just an example, i tried `100%`, it generated the same less quality image, and the original size is `32x31`.

Comment: Have you got a much larger original that you could start from instead of one that is only a tiny bit bigger? It might help if you posted the image too...

Comment: Please check the image's above.